# GUI to control wcf service

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

Is it possible to create a GUI(winform) to control wcf service and send data to the client connected to the service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, well, a GUI to *call* the service; *controlling**, I would say, is something else, but it no less possible.

<sub>*Controlling for me would be an app that sits alongside it able to turn it on, off, reset, etc. Something completely different to utilising it.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes - just because mostly anything's possible with C# :-)

Long answer: It depends on what you want to control. If you want to turn the service on/off, you better implement it as a Windows Service and use the Windows means for controlling services. If you want to "change settings" within the service then also: yes, this would just be another client.

To sent messages from the service to the client, it's best to implement a callback contract (also called two-way-communication). See here: http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx